# Last link not appearing (markdown bug?)

Tags: support, markdown

I just put some effort in giving links in this answer

[Where to find an overview of backed Collection methods/classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683286/where-to-find-an-overview-of-backed-collection-methods-classes/3683334#3683334)

And the last link never appeared as link:

- tried the `[..][1]` syntax (using the GUI)
- tried `<a href=".."`
- tried pasting the link directly without any modifications

The last link never appeared. (In preview it was fine)

That's why I put an empty `<a href="">.</a>`, so that it becomes last, and then the last-but-one is shown properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[This tutorial][1] has all information about collection:

- <a href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html"> implementations  
- [wrapper implementations][2] and [convenience implementations][3]  (what you are looking for)

(`subMap` is not there though. I can't see it in the `Map` interface actually)

  [1]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html
  [2]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html
  [3]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/convenience.html
```

You forgot the `</a>` after implementations in the first listed item, I guess that causes the trouble.

Why are you using a direct HTML-link there anyway?